# Magento 2: Dependency Injection: Optional class as parameter

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, magento2.3, di

We are developing a Magento 2 extension and we need to inject a class from a third party extension that the user may or may not have installed.

We thought about injecting the class via the **di.xml** file and set as an optional parameter in the class constructor.

When we run `'bin/magento setup:di:compile'` no errors are thrown, however when refreshing the pages, a class not found exception is thrown.

How can we check that the class exists before injecting in the **di.xml**?

I have something like this in my **di.xml**:

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="My\Custom\Class\Builder">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="thirdPartyHelper" xsi:type="object">Third\Party\Helper</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

And something like this in the class that i'm trying to inject:

```
    class Builder
    {
        private $dependency1;
        private $thidPartyHelper;

        public function __construct(
            Dependency1 $dependency1,
            ThidPartyHelper $thidPartyHelper = null
        ) {
            $this->dependency1 = $dependency1;
            $this->thidPartyHelper = $thidPartyHelper;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this in your di.xml `<type name="My\Custom\Builder">`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First Approach:**
The cleanest way is to not take decisions in the constructor.
Let the `di.xml` do that for you.
Let's say the core class you are using if a module is not present is `Some\Core\ClassName`.
And the class that should use this core class us `My\Custom\ClassName`.

And the class that might not exist is `MyExtension\PerhapsNotInstalled\ClassThatMightNotExist`

Make your class constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Some\Core\ClassName $object 
) {
    $this->_object = $object;
}
```

Now, in your module `MyExtension_PerhapsNotInstalled` `di.xml` file add this:

```
<type name="My\Custom\ClassName">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="object" xsi:type="object">MyExtension\PerhapsNotInstalled\ClassThatMightNotExist</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

just make sure that `MyExtension\PerhapsNotInstalled\ClassThatMightNotExist` extends the core class `Some\Core\ClassName`.

This way, if the module `MyExtension_PerhapsNotInstalled` is not installed, the original core class `Some\Core\ClassName` will be used, otherwise `MyExtension\PerhapsNotInstalled\ClassThatMightNotExist` will be used.

**Second Approach:**
If your extension that might not exist, is a third party extension that you cannot control, and you want your code to work with it and without it, you can do this (using the same notations as above):

Create your own class that acts as a factory:
Let's call it `My\Module\Factory`

```
<?php 

namespace My\Module;
class Factory
{
    protected $moduleManager;
    protected $objectManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }
    public function create(array $data = array())
    {
        if ($this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('ThirdPartyExtension_PerhapsNotInstalled')) {
            $instanceName =  'MyExtension\PerhapsNotInstalled\ClassThatMightNotExist';
        } else {
            $instanceName = 'Some\Core\ClassName';
        }
        return $this->objectManager->create($instanceName, $data);
    }
}
```

You should inject this new class in the constructor of your `My\Custom\ClassName` class and call  the `create` method from it to determine the class instance you need.

```
public function __construct(
    \My\Module\Factory $factory 
) {
    $this->_object = $factory->create();
}
```

Note: This second approach is not really clean, because in theory your dependencies should be explicit and the composition should be done via `di.xml` but I certainly understand the need.
Second Note: You are not violating any guidelines of not using the object manager, because OM is allowed in factories and you just created a factory.
And your class does not depend on the OM directly.
I didn't test the code, so watch out for syntax errors.

Ref : [Magento2: Checking if a module exists, after being injected via class constructor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173459/magento2-checking-if-a-module-exists-after-being-injected-via-class-constructo)

Answer (score 3):

You could inject a factory in the constructor that returns the optional object when it's available and a null object otherwise.

You could use ModuleList to see if the class/module is available.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a quick way to do this for a private script, without messing around with factories and other nonsense.

You can just check in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager            $moduleManager,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface    $objectManager
) {
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

    if ($moduleManager->isEnabled("MyOptionalModule_MyModule")) {
        $this->optionalModule = $objectManager->get("\My\Optional\Module");
    }
}
```